# Why is beta negative decay more common than beta positive?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

In simple terms, why is beta negative decay more common than beta positive?

I know it's something to do with occuring inside/outside the nucleus - but I can't find a simple, easy to understand explanation!

Comment: What does "more common" mean here? More common among fission products? More common in the earth's crust?

Answer (score 9):

The beta-decay may be "locally" reduced to a decay of a proton or a neutron inside a nucleus. The beta-minus decay contains the microscopic process
$$ n\to p + e^- + \bar \nu_e  + O(1{\rm \,MeV})$$
where the last term indicates the rough increase of the kinetic energy of the decay products. On the other hand, the beta-plus decay contains the process
$$ p  + O(1{\rm \,MeV})\to n + e^+ + \nu_e  $$
which means that the proton has to acquire some extra energy if it wants to decay to a neutron and a positron. In realistic beta-plus decays, it takes it from the surrounding nucleons in the nucleus.

Obviously, decays to lighter products where the energy conservation allows to give the final products some extra kinetic energy are more frequent than decays which only occur if an extra energy is found at the beginning. For example, among the bare processes above (for free nucleons), only the decay of the neutron may occur. The proton is stable (ignoring very infrequent processes linked to grand unification).

At the end, the inequality between the two types of the decay boils down primarily to the fact that the neutron is heavier than the proton which subsequently boils down to the fact that the down-quark is heavier than the up-quark (the rest masses).

Comment: And there is K-capture, a kind of beta positive.

Comment: I haven't done anything with the kinetic energy of the decay products before - and yet this is still a question we have. Is there a simpler way of explaining it without discussing kinetic energy?

Comment: Dear @Georg, you should be careful about the terminology. K-capture is sometimes called "inverse beta decay" but "beta negative decay" – despite the similar origin of "negative" and "inverse" – has to include positron emission. Comparisons of beta decays emitting electrons or positrons with K-capture is a subtle question because the two classes are qualitatively different.

Comment: Dear @ParachutingPanda, could you please be more specific about which concepts we are allowed to use in the answer if the concept of energy is already too difficult?

Comment: Would it be too much to ask about the origin and function of W and Z bosons in relation to this question?

Comment: @LubošMotl Well we've just learn that beta positive is proton>neutron, and occurs inside the nucleus, and beta negative is neutron>proton and it occurs outside the nucleus. There must be a simpler way of explaining it! :)

Comment: Nope, @ParachutingPanda, both proper beta-decays, positive and negative, occur inside the nucleus. I don't know how to simplify this thing more than the trivial assertion it is now. Can you please define "simple"? AdamRedwine: all beta-decays are ultimately mediated by W-bosons. (There are also similar interactions mediated by Z-bosons, but they only occur - with a few irrelevant exceptions - when there is an electromagnetic interaction of the same kind as well, and the electromagnetic one is much more important in such cases.) W-bosons only become important at high energies, 100 GeV or so...

Comment: @ParachutingPanda: sometimes there is no simpler explanation.

Comment: This just seems wrong to me. The mass difference between the neutron and the proton is relevant only in the case of the beta decay of a free neutron. In other nuclei, the Q value depends on a lot of nuclear structure. In general, the prevalence of $\beta^+$ versus $\beta^-$ decay simply depends on which side of the line of stability you're on, so this is completely a question of which nuclei we're considering: neutron-rich or proton-rich.

Comment: No doubt about it, the significantly proton-neutron-asymmetric nuclei have a preference. But it's still true that beta minus is more widespread than beta plus among nuclei we may meet, right? And it's correlated to the heavier neutron relatively to the proton.

Comment: Here you have the graph with the beta-minus and beta-plus decays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-decay_stable_isobars At least for the lighter nuclei, beta-minus is more frequent, isn't it? Do you agree that the heavier mass of the neutron may be said to be the reason why it's so? There are simply many neutrons that are more likely to decay to protons than vice versa. Only the isotopes near Z=N are stable enough because those that are very far alpha decay! So given they don't alpha-decay too quickly, beta-minus decay is more widespread than beta-plus.

Answer (score 9):

Beta-minus decay occurs in nuclei with an excess of neutrons, while beta-plus decay takes place in  neutron-deficit  nuclei. A lot of natural background radiation on Earth is due to fission or alpha-decay of  heavy radioactive elements. The remains of  fission or alpha-decay are neutron-rich nuclei, so beta-minus decay is more common on Earth.

Whereas [on stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) beta-plus decay is typical, because  neutron-deficit nuclei are produced in nuclear fusion.

Comment: I would just add that "neutron heavy" or "neutron deficit" is relative to the island of stability, not N=Z.  I remember that there is one process for one direction and 2 processes for the other direction, so in that context I think you're missing one.  Internal capture for N-1 and Z+1?  Anyway, that's not fully in the scope of the question.

Comment: @Zassounotsukushi, is relative to the [**line** of stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-decay_stable_isobars)

Answer (score 5):

(The following extends Georg's remarks earlier, where K-capture refers to K-electron capture.)

Beta-plus decay competes with electron capture, but there are few positrons around for beta-minus decay to compete with, so even when beta-plus decay is possible, its branching ratio may be small or overwhelmed by EC.

Moreover, in EC (versus beta-plus decay) the energy difference between initial state and final benefits from the addition of an electron to the reactant side and loss of a positron on the product side (so about 1MeV total).  So some nuclei decay by EC that can't decay by positron emission.